# How To read disk from dead Zyxel NAS

Tags: external-hard-drive, nas, hard-drive-recovery

I have the harddrive fra a Zyxel NAS. The NAS is dead, but the harddrive seems okay. How can I access it? If I mount it in af USB harddrive case, Windows can see the disk in Disk Manager, but Explorer can't read it.
I have tried to install Oracle VirtualMachine with Ubuntu, but that can't read it either.

Any good ideas?

Comment: Better ask Zyxel directly and/or use their forum. It uses some form of RAID but exact details may not be public.

Comment: True. Reasonably chance that it is MD. In which case other answers on this site like https://superuser.com/questions/1499998/rebuild-a-raid5-on-zyxel-nas-540?rq=1 might help.